# Background color error when using multiple cameras

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I put a black ambient/background to the scene of a world during a simulation, and I observe it with a model containing multiple cameras.
The first camera included in the model will get the normal image as background, but the second onwards get a luminous one (or, when using plugins, it seems it is the first camera that actually produces an image that gets the good background).

Here is the model world used:

```
<?xml version ='1.0'?>
<sdf version ='1.4'>
  <world name='default'>
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://hopping</uri>
    </include>

    <scene>
      <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
      <background>0 0 0 1</background>
    </scene>
</world>
</sdf>
```

with hopping containing identical camera sensors (just with a name change):

```
<include>
  <uri>model://noisy_cam2</uri>
  <name>camera2</name>
  <pose>-0.05 -0.05 0.05 0 -0.785 -2.08</pose>
</include>
<joint name="camera_joint2" type="revolute">
  <child>camera2::link</child>
  <parent>chassis</parent>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    <limit>
      <upper>0</upper>
      <lower>0</lower>
    </limit>
  </axis>
</joint>
<include>
  <uri>model://noisy_cam1</uri>
  <name>camera1</name>
  <pose>0.05 0.0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
<joint name="camera_joint" type="revolute">
  <child>camera1::link</child>
  <parent>chassis</parent>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    <limit>
      <upper>0</upper>
      <lower>0</lower>
    </limit>
  </axis>
</joint>
```

With gztopic view /gazebo/.../image, for instance, by changing the views, there are not the same (sorry, my karma is way too low for uploading images, so here are screenshots uploaded to imgur)

[camera2 (normal black background)](https://i.imgur.com/4l7hiPz.png)

[camera1 (way too gray, background not black)](https://i.imgur.com/492M8Hc.png)

Other than this wrong background, the images are fine, if someone has any idea ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5103/background-color-error-when-using-multiple-cameras/) by [altrouge](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/583/altrouge/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems it was due to the fact my cameras used noise.
I used the model described in the tutorial,

```
<camera>
  <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
  <image>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>1024</height>
  </image>
  <clip>
    <near>0.1</near>
    <far>100</far>
  </clip>
  <noise>
    <type>gaussian</type>
    <mean>0.0</mean>
    <stddev>0.007</stddev>
  </noise>
</camera>
```

Without this noise, I don't have the background color error anymore.
I don't really know if it was specific to my platform.

---

Originally posted by [altrouge](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/583/altrouge/) with karma: 26 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1